# Portable way to add dates between Oracle and MySQL?

Tags: mysql, oracle, portability, date-math

Is there any way to add dates/times that will be portable between Oracle and MySQL?

For example, in Oracle, adding `col + 1` to a date column will add a day.

In MySQL, adding `col + 1` to a `datetime` column will add a SECOND.

Is there a function that would give the same results in both?

(I'm trying to use this in an `order by`, for example, `order by col1 + col2/(60*24)` - if it were part of the SELECT or WHERE, there might be better options.)

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you need to use the same function?

Comment: And `ORDER BY DateColumn` is equivalent to both `ORDER BY DateColumn + 1 sec` and `ORDER BY DateColumn + 1 DAY`

Comment: see edits - not just adding a constant, adding value from another column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select datecolumn + interval '1' day 
from your_table
```

works with [Oracle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/2795) and [MySQL](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/2288)

Comment: So close ... How can I do that where the '1' is an expression rather than a string constant?  `date + interval (expr) day` works fine in MySQL but Oracle seems to only allow string.

Comment: @wrschneider99: I don't think an expression is possible there (didn't expect it work at all actually).

Comment: @wrschneider99 I think you will need to do `expr * interval '1' day`.  I don't think `interval (expr) day` is part of the standard.

Comment: `expr * interval '1' day` works in Oracle but not MySQL.  Accepting answer anyway since it seems to be the closest we can get.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to create an app that will work on oracle and MySQL using the same set of queries, did you consider shipping a script with it that will create stored procedures to do the minor work you require e.g. creating a DATE_ADD_DAYS procedure that you then call. The sproc contains the db specific stuff and your app contains only calls to these sprocs you know will exist (because they're in your install script)